# What is the real gas equation at high pressures?

Tags: gas-laws

Is it correct to ignore the $\frac{n^2a}{V^2}$ term at high pressures as is done? I think that, as pressure increases, this term also increases as Volume decreases so it is not safe to ignore it!

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16110/the-van-der-waals-equation-high-t-and-high-v-m